# Why does bootstrap allow me to use col-xs-13 but not col-xs-12?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a section that contains two articles, each classed as "col-xs-6".  Both articles pair nicely side-side, taking up the full-width.
After this, I have an aside and a footer, each classed as "col-xs-12"; however, these are a little shy of full-width.
But when I change their classes to "col-xs-13", it becomes full width. I understand that I could change all the classes to "col-s-12" and fix the problem, but if the 2 xs-6 articles add to full width, shouldn't a single xs-12 do the same? Why not?

```css
body {
  background: #F0E68C;
  text-align: left;
}
header {
  background: green;
}
nav {
  background: blue;
}
section {
  background: orange;
}
article {
  background: red;
}
aside {
  background: yellow;
}
footer {
  background: orange;
}
section {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<body class="container-fluid">
  <header class="jumbotron bg-primary text-center">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Your menu</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section class="row">
    <article class="col-xs-6">
      <header>
        <h2>Article title</h2> 
        <p>Posted on
          <time datetime="2009-09-04T16:31:24+02:00">September 4th 2009</time>by <a href="#">Writer</a> - <a href="#comments">6 comments</a>
        </p>
      </header>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    </article>
    <article class="col-xs-6">
      <header>
        <h2>Article title</h2> 
        <p>Posted on
          <time datetime="2009-09-04T16:31:24+02:00">September 4th 2009</time>by <a href="#">Writer</a> - <a href="#comments">6 comments</a>
        </p>
      </header>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    </article>
  </section>
  <aside class="row col-xs-13">
    <h2>About section</h2> 
    <p>Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </aside>
  <footer class="row col-xs-13">
    <p>Copyright 2009 Your name</p>
  </footer>
```

Comment: There is no `col-xs-13` in Bootstrap because the grid consists of 12 columns. You're just creating a div without padding when you use `col-xs-13` because no styles are defined for that class. All of the Bootstrap `col-*` s have padding on the left/right of 15px

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap `col-*-*` class definitions add `15px` `padding-left` and `padding-right`. `col-*-13` does not exist in the standard Bootstrap 3 style sheet so no column padding is being applied making it look like it's more full width as `row` has negative margins `-15px` on left and right effectively expanding the space it takes.

These positive paddings on the `col-*-*` combined with negative margins of the `row` class definitions ensure that the grid functions correctly. I'd avoid removing them.

If you need to make elements seem more "full-width", but within the standard `container` sizing. You can try wrapping elements in custom class and give it a background/pattern/etc.

From the Bootstrap documentation:

> Columns create gutters (gaps between column content) via padding. That
>   padding is offset in rows for the first and last column via negative
>   margin on .rows.
>
> The negative margin is why the examples below are outdented. It's so
>   that content within grid columns is lined up with non-grid content.

Answer (score 1):

> But when I change their classes to "col-xs-13", it becomes full width.

It's because `col-xs-13` class don't have width set on the bootstrap css. So by default it takes full width since the elements where you've put are block elements.

> I understand that I could change all the classes to "col-s-12" and fix
>   the problem, but if the 2 xs-6 articles add to full width, shouldn't a
>   single xs-12 do the same? Why not?

It's because you've put the `col-xs-12` class along side with the `row` class. The `row` class should be the parent in order for the `col-*-*` classes to work.

So from this:

```
  <aside class="row col-xs-13">
    <h2>About section</h2> 
    <p>Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </aside>
  <footer class="row col-xs-13">
    <p>Copyright 2009 Your name</p>
  </footer>
```

To:

```
  <div class="row">
    <aside class="col-xs-12">
      <h2>About section</h2>
      <p>Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
    </aside>
    <footer class="col-xs-12">
      <p>Copyright 2009 Your name</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
```